# PHP: Convert a UNIX timestamp into local time (as integer)

Tags: php

For a simple PHP graphing script, I need to align time values at local time days. When I do something like `$timestamp % 86400 == 0` I get a break at 2 am every day because I'm in UTC +2 here. Also all my grid lines are at 2am, 5am, 8am etc. instead of 0am, 3am, 6am etc.

I understand that UNIX timestamp integer values are *always* in UTC and that there's `date()` and `gmdate()` and such, but I need an integer in local time to do arithmetics on it. How would I do that in PHP? Is there a function such as `ToLocalTime()` and `ToUniversalTime()` like in .NET?

To clarify the question, I have nothing to do with readable formatting of the time. No YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS or the like, I just deal with numbers. The input is a number of seconds since epoch in UTC, aka the UNIX timestamp. What I need is a number of the same kind but not in UTC but local time. So I need to convert a UNIX timestamp integer into a local timestamp integer. Hope this is understandable and anybody can imagine what this could be used for (aligning grid lines in a time-axis graph at local time).

Comment: **Don't** do such calculations with timestamps. Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and its relatives.

Comment: Why do you think that timestamp is UTC but not local server time?

Comment: @axiac Then how would you suggest finding a start time aligned by 3 hours? Modulo is simple. Can the DateTime class do that?

Comment: @splash58 It's by definition. Do your own tests and you'll find that a timestamp is seconds since epoch in UTC, not local time.

Comment: The `DateTime` class can do more than that. It also take care of the DST, timezones, date formatting, date time operations (addition, subtraction of date intervals).

Comment: @axiac Could you please tell me how? The documentation seems to be incomplete and I can't guess method names like "align to hours".

Comment: There is no such thing as "local" timestamp. A timestamp is an absolute value: the number of seconds passed from a fixed moment in the past. The local time is a partial representation of a timestamp. It is relative to a timezone.

Comment: @LonelyPixel What do you mean by "align to hours"? Edit the question, add an example of what you want to get.

Comment: $timestamp - strtotime('midnight', $timestamp)

Comment: Have you ever seen a time-axis graph that shows a grid line every three hours? Those lines were probably not at 2am, 5am and 8am but rather 0am, 3am and 6am. I need to do that sort of alignment to "round" numbers.

Comment: and how you get "local" timestamp? mybe, you need revert the algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this to determine the local time UTC offset:

```
$tzoffset = date('Z');
```

Then I just add or subtract that value to timestamps and treat them like UTC times but they are really local times. Technically they are always "off" the real time I intend to work with, but that shift corrects the difference between UTC and local time and lets me do the maths on local times in the "UTC space". When I'm done, I can transform the time back into "local space" for displaying. I could also use the `gmdate` function and get local time format.

```
$now = time() + $tzoffset;
echo gmdate('...', $now);   // Prints local time
if ($now % 86400 == 0 && gmdate('w', $now) == 1)
{
    echo 'Monday midnight local time';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [datetime class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and set the `date_default_timezone_set`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

---

Update based on your comments:

> I have a timestamp that is not "now" and need to apply DST offset to
>   it.

`PHP` takes care of DST. The necessary conversion rules are part of the `PHP` installation.

---

NOTE:

**The unix timestamp isn't affected by a timezone settings**. Setting the timezone only affects the interpretation of the timestamp value.

Comment: Wow, how did you find the `getTimestamp` method? It's not documented but I need it anyway. Apart from that it's not what I need. I have a timestamp that is not "now" and need to apply DST offset to it.

Comment: PHP takes care of DST. The necessary conversion rules are part of the PHP installation.

Comment: Still not helpful, sorry.

Comment: I guess you'll have to update your question including a clear example and desired output.

Comment: It happens... tks!

Comment: I did one downvote and now removed it to let you read my clarified question. Hope this helps. I had thought it would be clear.

Comment: Setting the timezone and then getting the timestamp does nothing. `getTimestamp` will always give me the original value converted to UTC, I get the same as $input.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go is using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) API.
So you can handle timezones via DateTimeZone class, something like this:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$UTCDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i','2016-05-01 10:00', $timezone);

# by your local timezone
$newDate = $UTCDate->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

Comment: Again, how will this help me finding "round" numbers, aligned to 24 or 3 hours of local time? If I have an integer of it, I can use modulo.

Comment: @LonelyPixel well, now you know where to go I think you should dive into in PHP manual. You already have the fishing rod. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation:

```
// Europe/Bucharest is GMT+2 (GMT+3 during DST)
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest');

$now = new DateTime('now', $tz);    // now (2016-05-01 14:50:23, local time)
$dayStart = clone $now;
$dayStart->setTime(0, 0, 0);    // start of today (2016-05-01 00:00:00, local time)
$dayEnd = clone $now;
$dayEnd->setTime(23, 59, 59);   // end of today (2016-05-01 23:59:59, local time)

// If you need the timestamps (to compare with MySQL TIMESTAMP columns)
printf("%d .. %d\n", $dayStart->getTimestamp(), $dayEnd->getTimestamp());
// It prints: 1462050000 .. 1462136399


// If you need the dates in UTC timezone (to compare with MySQL DATETIME columns)
$tzUTC = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$dayStart->setTimezone($tzUTC);
$dayEnd->setTimezone($tzUTC);
printf("%s .. %s\n", $dayStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $dayEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
// It prints: 2016-04-30 21:00:00 .. 2016-05-01 20:59:59
```

**Update**

In order to get the local time every three hours you can use the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class:

```
// A 3 hours interval
$interval = new DateInterval('PT3H');
// A period that starts at today's 00:00:00 (local time) and ends at 23:59:59
$period = new DatePeriod($dayStart, $interval, $dayEnd);
// Iterate over it to get the moments every 3 hours
foreach ($period as $moment) {
    echo($moment->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n");
}
```

If you append this piece of code to the code above, you will get the dates represented in UTC. If you skip the block of the code that changes the timezones of `$dayStart` and `$dayEnd` then the code above will print:

```
2016-05-01 00:00:00
2016-05-01 03:00:00
2016-05-01 06:00:00
2016-05-01 09:00:00
2016-05-01 12:00:00
2016-05-01 15:00:00
2016-05-01 18:00:00
2016-05-01 21:00:00
```